# How to make GPU PerfStudio & GLEW play nicely?

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, glew, gpu-perfstudio

I have a basic application which runs just fine, uses OpenGL 4.3 core profile & GLEW 1.11.0.
However, when I run it through GPU PerfStudio, it crashes right on glewInit, yielding an error saying "Missing GL version".
The context is created before `glewInit` is called, of course (and as mentioned it runs perfectly fine on its own).

How can this problem be solved?

**Update:**
Win32 binaries work perfectly fine - this only happens with x64.

Comment: Are you sure PerfStudio supports that version?Try GL 3.3

Comment: @MichaelIV I am sure. PerfStudio's welcome page mentions that OpenGL 4.3 is supported.

Comment: What additional libraries are you using? You cannot create a 4.3 core profile without loading at least one WGL extension, so I have to imagine you're not using straight Win32/WGL API to create your context.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman freeglut